# Работа с камерой в UWP и добавление эффектов

Tags: uwp, видео

Добрый день. Добавляю эффекты к mediaCapture: `await _mediaCapture.AddVideoEffectAsync(new VideoEffectDefinition(typeName),MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);`, все работает и эффект добавляется, но проблема с очисткой эффектов:

```
await _mediaCapture.ClearEffectsAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);
await Task.Delay(200);
await _mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(previewFrame);
```

На последней строчке уходит в catch с ошибкой:

> Invalid subtype
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at App1.MainPage.d__44.MoveNext()

Из-за чего это происходит? При этом, если эффекты не очищать, то всё нормально. Заранее спасибо